# Null expected revenue value gamma gamma fitter >- conditional_expected_average_profit function

Tags: python

1. I fit the lifetimes gamma gamma fitter to data as follows:-

## fit the GG model

```
ggf = GammaGammaFitter(penalizer_coef=1e-06)
ggf.fit(
    frequency = df_rftv["frequency"],
monetary_value = df_rftv["monetary_value"],
weights = None,
verbose = True,
tol = 1e-06,
q_constraint = True)

#pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
ggf.summary
```

2. Here is the summary of the data frame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jHng.png)

3. Next when I run conditional_expected_average_profit function of the gamma gamma fitter object , the expected revenue (exp_avg_rev) is all "null" Don't know why??? Please help!

   exp_avg_rev = ggf.conditional_expected_average_profit(
   df_rftv["frequency"],
   df_rftv["monetary_value"])

   df_rftv["exp_avg_rev"] = exp_avg_rev
   df_rftv["avg_rev"] = df_rftv["monetary_value"]
   df_rftv["error_rev"] = df_rftv["exp_avg_rev"] - df_rftv["avg_rev"]
   #mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(exp_avg_rev, df_rftv["monetary_value"])
   #print("MAPE of predicted revenues:", f'{mape:.2f}')

   df_rftv.head()

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is with the q coefficient from GammaGammaFitter, where it stays 1 and generating infinite values.

Try this manual code to see what i'm talking about:

```
p = #your p coefficient value
q = #your q coefficient value
v = #your v coefficient value

x = df_rftv['frequency']
m = df_rftv['monetary_value']

summary_with_money_value['predicted_profit'] = ((((q - 1) / (p * x + q - 1)) * (v * p / (q - 1))) + (p * x / (p * x + q - 1)) * m)
```